# Mixed effects model (?) with known data uncertainty

Tags: mixed-model, heteroscedasticity

I have been given data from a number of replicate experiments, each of which provides both a value and a standard error. I would like to arrive at a single estimate of this value and its standard error.

To be concrete, imagine I have 10 replicate experiments, each of which gives me a value y_i and an estimated standard error s_i (for i=1 to 10). I want to come up with an estimate for y, assuming each experiment has its own random deviation from y, together with its own estimated standard error (s_i).

This seems like a two-level mixed effects model, where the random effect is the experiment-to-experiment variability, and the residual variation is encapsulated by the s_i values (and is heteroskedastic because not all s_i are equal). What differs from what see can be specified in `lme` is that we know the actual variances, not only their ratios (which you would specify using `varIdent()` for example).

Thoughts on how to proceed? One thought would be just to simulate a bunch of data with variances corresponding to those s_i values. But it seems like there should be a simpler way.

thanks
Dan

Comment: Do you only have the summary data from the 10 experiments? If you only have the summary data, this isn't a mixed effects model. With `lm()`, you can simply regress the 10 response data points on a constant (intercept) while weighting by the inverse of the squared standard errors. I think this should be a reasonable option.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. My only concern is that the weights in `lm()` have no absolute scale. Whereas here I'd the standard errors to propagate to the overall uncertainty of my final estimator, and they do have an absolute scale. If these standard errors are large, then my final estimator should also be very uncertain. To be specific, these values come from a nonlinear estimation of IC50 from dose-response data, where the IC50 estimates come with error bars. I'd like to be sure that the weak experiments have weak impact, but also that their errors propagate.

Comment: I can not judge the extent to which your concern matters. Such inverse-variance weighting is WLS which should be a more efficient estimator of the mean. One would expect that more noisy experiments will also have more varied estimates themselves, such that the final mean will deviate more from the true population mean when there are more shabby estimates, even though in the long run, it may be unbiased. Also, final SE will naturally be larger. WLS is designed for all this when you have the variances of the estimates.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you only have the summary data from the 10 experiments. If you only have the summary data, this isn't a mixed effects model. With `lm()`, you can simply regress the 10 response data points on a constant (intercept) while weighting by the inverse of the squared standard errors. Such inverse-variance weighting is WLS which should be a more efficient estimator of the mean.